# PHP function run on localhost but not on my server

Tags: php, mysql, json, function, webserver

In a .php page I have the function below. In localhost the JSON response is different than NULL, but when I put the page in on the server (FTP) the JSON response is NULL.

**THE CODE**

```
// Check for required parameters
if (isset($_POST["placetype"]) && isset($_POST["placeName"])) {
  $pt = $_POST["placetype"];
  $pn = $_POST["placeName"];
  $dir = 'Pictures/Attractions/'.$pt.'/'.$pn.'/';
  $files = scandir($dir);
  foreach($files as $ind_file) {
    $result[] = array(
      "data" => $ind_file
    );
  sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
  return true;
}//ifisset
sendResponse(400, 'Invalid request');
return false;
```

**Note**: the same folders are on both local and on the server.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you run php5 or greater on your webserver?

Comment: What exactly does this `sendReponse` function do? It's not a standard PHP function. As well, you'll get NULL as json if the path you're generating doesn't exist - you never set $result to be anything UNLESS at least one file is found.

Comment: The $dir path exists on the server? Verify path.

Comment: Could be a file permission problem. Can the webserver user read the pictures folder?

Comment: @ShogunArts.de Server version: 5.1.59-community

Comment: And **please** sanitize your input. What happens if `$_POST["placeName"] = '../../../folder_with_all_my_passwords'`?

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon yes it exists

Comment: @Bobj-C json_encode comes from  5.2.0

Comment: @pixelistik yes the pictures can open in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this

```
$files = scandir($dir);
```

If you haven't files in $dir, you variable $result will not create and will hold nothing, json will return null. On remote server you haven't files and json_encode return null

Comment: Yup the $files is empty i should write $ dir ='./Pictures/Attractions/'.$pt.'/'.$pn.'/';

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the PHP install on your server is not up to date. `json_encode()` only works with PHP 5 >= 5.2.0.

Comment: Others .php files are contains bunch of json_encode and they are working properly.